# Gluon Basic Project not working

Tags: android, netbeans, javafx, javafxports, gluon

I followed [Gluon Tutorial to deploy JavaFX on Android](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/2.0.0/#_ide_plugins). 
From the start i have troubles, when i create a new gluon basic project i already have an error. On desktop work fine, on tasks -> :android, don't work. I search and find, need to update the project and i follow [Managing Projects](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#UpdatingAProject) to do it, and actually i can do tasks -> :androidInstall with no problem.
But on the emulator, i start the app and only appears a black screen, i run adb logcat and this is the output:

```
tivityManager( 4042): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.gluonfx/javafxports.a
id.FXActivity} from pid 4160
ndowManager( 4042): Failure taking screenshot for (328x546) to layer 21005
rfaceFlinger(   36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
lvikvm( 7339): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
tivityManager( 4042): Start proc com.gluonfx for activity com.gluonfx/javafxports.android.FXActivity: pid=7339 uid=10049 gids={50049, 3003, 1028,
}
ace   ( 7339): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
ltiDex( 7339): VM with version 1.6.0 does not have multidex support
ltiDex( 7339): install
ltiDex( 7339): MultiDexExtractor.load(/data/app/com.gluonfx-1.apk, false)
ltiDex( 7339): loading existing secondary dex files
ltiDex( 7339): load found 1 secondary dex files
ltiDex( 7339): install done
Activity( 7339): Initializing JavaFX Platform, using 8.60.6-SNAPSHOT
lvikvm( 7339): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.gluonfx-1/libactivity.so 0x40cd48c8
lvikvm( 7339): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.gluonfx-1/libactivity.so 0x40cd48c8
Activity native( 7339): Loading JavaFXDalvik library
Activity( 7339): onCreate called, using 8.60.6-SNAPSHOT
Activity native( 7339): Notification queue instance created.
Activity native( 7339): Notification queue started
Activity native( 7339): appDataDir: /data/data/com.gluonfx
Activity( 7339): onStart
Activity( 7339): onResume
rfaceFlinger(   36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
rfaceFlinger(   36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
Entity( 7339): Surface created.
Entity( 7339): metrics = DisplayMetrics{density=2.0, width=768, height=1184, scaledDensity=2.0, xdpi=320.0, ydpi=320.0}
Activity native( 7339): [JVDBG] SURFACE created native android window at 0x2a1b4f28, surface = 0xb9b0001d
lvikvm( 7339): GC_CONCURRENT freed 197K, 9% free 2670K/2928K, paused 5ms+17ms, total 55ms
lvikvm( 7339): GC_CONCURRENT freed 184K, 8% free 2964K/3220K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 30ms
lvikvm( 7339): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 11ms
lvikvm( 7339): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 289K, 15% free 2999K/3492K, paused 20ms, total 21ms
lvikvm( 7339): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 241K, 14% free 3076K/3556K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
lvikvm( 7339): GC_CONCURRENT freed 233K, 10% free 3277K/3636K, paused 6ms+12ms, total 48ms
lvikvm( 7339): GC_CONCURRENT freed 242K, 8% free 3521K/3824K, paused 4ms+12ms, total 50ms
lvikvm( 7339): GC_CONCURRENT freed 117K, 5% free 3839K/4016K, paused 4ms+6ms, total 58ms
stem.out( 7339): java.vm.version=1.6.0
stem.out( 7339): use.egl=true
stem.out( 7339): java.vendor.url=http://www.android.com/
stem.out( 7339): java.vm.vendor.url=http://www.android.com/
stem.out( 7339): user.dir=/
stem.out( 7339): prism.text=native
stem.out( 7339): glass.platform=Monocle
stem.out( 7339): com.sun.javafx.gestures.rotate=true
stem.out( 7339): java.io.tmpdir=/data/data/com.gluonfx/cache
stem.out( 7339): user.home=
stem.out( 7339): com.sun.javafx.gestures.zoom=true
stem.out( 7339): http.agent=Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.2.2...
stem.out( 7339): java.version=0
stem.out( 7339): javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.sun.xml.stream.ZephyrParserFactory
stem.out( 7339): file.encoding=UTF-8
stem.out( 7339): line.separator=
stem.out( 7339): java.vm.specification.vendor=The Android Project
stem.out( 7339): com.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true
stem.out( 7339): prism.glDepthSize=16
stem.out( 7339): android.openssl.version=OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
stem.out( 7339): prism.allowhidpi=true
stem.out( 7339): java.vm.vendor=The Android Project
stem.out( 7339): DALVIK.prism.verbose=true
stem.out( 7339): embedded=monocle
stem.out( 7339): java.class.path=.
stem.out( 7339): glass.lens=eglfb
stem.out( 7339): user.language=en
stem.out( 7339): user.name=
stem.out( 7339): os.arch=armv7l
stem.out( 7339): java.runtime.version=0.9
stem.out( 7339): com.sun.javafx.gestures.scroll=true
stem.out( 7339): android.icu.library.version=4.8.1.1
stem.out( 7339): prism.debugfonts=true
stem.out( 7339): javafx.platform=android
stem.out( 7339): java.home=/system
stem.out( 7339): java.vm.name=Dalvik
stem.out( 7339): user.region=US
stem.out( 7339): android.zlib.version=1.2.7
stem.out( 7339): monocle.platform=Android
stem.out( 7339): java.runtime.name=Android Runtime
stem.out( 7339): prism.dirtyopts=true
stem.out( 7339): java.boot.class.path=/system/framework/core.jar:/system/fr...
stem.out( 7339): java.library.path=/vendor/lib:/system/lib
stem.out( 7339): file.separator=/
stem.out( 7339): prism.vsync=false
stem.out( 7339): javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory=com.sun.xml.stream.ZephyrWriterFactory
stem.out( 7339): java.specification.vendor=The Android Project
stem.out( 7339): java.vm.specification.version=0.9
stem.out( 7339): log.lens=FINEST
stem.out( 7339): prism.verbose=true
stem.out( 7339): os.name=Linux
stem.out( 7339): prism.lcdtext=false
stem.out( 7339): path.separator=:
stem.out( 7339): java.ext.dirs=
stem.out( 7339): prism.maxTextureSize=2048
stem.out( 7339): java.specification.name=Dalvik Core Library
stem.out( 7339): os.version=2.6.29-gea477bb
stem.out( 7339): java.compiler=
stem.out( 7339): android.icu.unicode.version=6.0
stem.out( 7339): java.class.version=50.0
stem.out( 7339): java.vendor=The Android Project
stem.out( 7339): javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory=com.sun.xml.stream.events.ZephyrEvent...
stem.out( 7339): java.vm.specification.name=Dalvik Virtual Machine Specification
stem.out( 7339): java.specification.version=0.9
lvikLauncher( 7339): Launch JavaFX application on DALVIK vm.
lvikLauncher( 7339): We have JavaFX on our current (base) classpath, registered exit listener
lvikLauncher( 7339): application class: [class com.gluonfx.GluonFX]
lvikLauncher( 7339): preloader class: [null]
lvikLauncher( 7339): javafx application class: [class javafx.application.Application]
lvikLauncher( 7339): javafx launcher class: [class com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl]
lvikLauncher( 7339): launch application method: [public static void com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(java.lang.Class,java
g.Class,java.lang.String[])]
Entity( 7339): Called Surface changed [768, 1134], format 4
Activity native( 7339): [JVDBG] SURFACE created native android window at 0x2a1b4f28, surface = 0x84d0001d
Entity( 7339): Called Surface redraw needed
oreographer( 7339): Skipped 116 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
Entity( 7339): Called Surface redraw needed
alloc_goldfish( 7339): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
stem.out( 7339): Prism pipeline init order: es2
stem.out( 7339): Using native-based Pisces rasterizer
stem.out( 7339): Using dirty region optimizations
stem.out( 7339): Using system sized mask for primitives
stem.out( 7339): Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
stem.out( 7339): Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
stem.out( 7339): Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
stem.out( 7339): Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
stem.out( 7339): Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2_monocle
lvikvm( 7339): dlopen("/vendor/lib/libprism_es2_monocle.so") failed: Cannot load library: load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "/vendor/lib/libpr
es2_monocle.so" not found
lvikvm( 7339): dlopen("/system/lib/libprism_es2_monocle.so") failed: Cannot load library: load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "/system/lib/libpr
es2_monocle.so" not found
lvikvm( 7339): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.gluonfx-1/libprism_es2_monocle.so 0x40cd48c8
lvikvm( 7339): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.gluonfx-1/libprism_es2_monocle.so 0x40cd48c8
lvikvm( 7339): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.gluonfx-1/libprism_es2_monocle.so 0x40cd48c8, skipping init
stem.out( 7339):    succeeded.
stem.out( 7339): GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.MonocleGLFactory
tivityManager( 4042): Displayed com.gluonfx/javafxports.android.FXActivity: +2s461ms
lvikvm( 7339): dlopen("/vendor/lib/libglass_monocle.so") failed: Cannot load library: load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "/vendor/lib/libglass_
cle.so" not found
lvikvm( 7339): dlopen("/system/lib/libglass_monocle.so") failed: Cannot load library: load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "/system/lib/libglass_
cle.so" not found
lvikvm( 7339): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.gluonfx-1/libglass_monocle.so 0x40cd48c8
lvikvm( 7339): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.gluonfx-1/libglass_monocle.so 0x40cd48c8
lvikvm( 7339): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.gluonfx-1/libglass_monocle.so 0x40cd48c8, skipping init
ASS   ( 7339): I have to Call dlopen libGLESv2.so
ASS   ( 7339): handle = 0x40012858
ASS   ( 7339): I have to Call dlopen libEGL.so
ASS   ( 7339): handle = 0x40012610
ASS   ( 7339): Binding to libactivity.so
ASS   ( 7339): GetNativeWindow = 0x4c860d05, getDensitiy = 0x4c860d11
Entity( 7339): notify_glassHasStarted called in FXActivity. register device now.
bEGL  ( 7339): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
bEGL  ( 7339): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
stem.err( 7339): com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.GLException: 0x3005: Could not get EGL surface
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.AcceleratedScreen.<init>(AcceleratedScreen.java:110)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.AndroidAcceleratedScreen.<init>(AndroidAcceleratedScreen.java:40)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.AndroidPlatform.getAcceleratedScreen(AndroidPlatform.java:59)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.prism.es2.MonocleGLFactory.initialize(MonocleGLFactory.java:107)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>(ES2Pipeline.java:81)
stem.err( 7339):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
stem.err( 7339):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
stem.err( 7339):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:187)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
stem.err( 7339):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
stem.out( 7339): (X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
stem.err( 7339): GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline: error initializing pipeline com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
stem.err( 7339): Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2
stem.err( 7339): Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
stem.err( 7339): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:221)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:198)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:209)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:695)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$137(LauncherImpl.java:182)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$lambda$1(LauncherImpl.java)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source)
stem.err( 7339):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
stem.err( 7339): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
stem.err( 7339):    ... 1 more
stem.err( 7339): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
stem.err( 7339):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
stem.err( 7339):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
stem.err( 7339):    at javafxports.android.DalvikLauncher$1.run(DalvikLauncher.java:188)
stem.err( 7339):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
stem.err( 7339): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:210)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:209)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:695)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$137(LauncherImpl.java:182)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$lambda$1(LauncherImpl.java)
stem.err( 7339):    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source)
stem.err( 7339):    ... 1 more
oreographer( 4160): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I already try other samples and none of them work. I really don't know what more can i do, but one fight at a time.
Can anyone help me, please? If more data is needed, I can upload it.

Comment: Can you deploy your project on a real device? Currently it won't work on the Android simulator. `Android` task will generate the apk, and you have to install it on your device. `AndroidInstall` will generate the apk and install it on your device.

Comment: Thank you Sir, i try to deploy the project on a real device and work just fine. Thank you for the help